# How to implement Graph using Adjacency List in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, adjacency-list

I am trying to implement an undirected graph in Java using adjacency list from the following resource: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/

The code runs without any errors but doesn't give any output. Here's the code:

```
class AdjListNode{
    int dest;
    AdjListNode next;

    public AdjListNode(int dest){
        this.dest = dest;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class AdjList{
    AdjListNode head;
}

public class graph{
    int V;
    AdjListNode newNode;
    AdjList array[];

    public graph(int V){
        this.V = V;
        this.array = new AdjList[V];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<V;++i){
            this.array[i].head = null;
        }
    }

    void addEdge(graph g, int src, int dest){
        newNode = new AdjListNode(dest);
        newNode.next = g.array[src].head;
        g.array[src].head = newNode;

        newNode = new AdjListNode(src);
        newNode.next = g.array[dest].head;
        g.array[dest].head = newNode;
    }

    void printGraph(graph g){
        int v;
        for(v=0;v < g.V;++v){
            AdjListNode pCrawl = g.array[v].head;
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Adjacency list of vertex "+v);
            System.out.print("head");
            while(pCrawl != null){
                System.out.print(pCrawl.dest);
                pCrawl = pCrawl.next;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int V = 5;
        graph g = new graph(V);
        g.addEdge(g,0,1);
        g.addEdge(g,0,4);
        g.addEdge(g,1,2);
        g.addEdge(g,1,3);
        g.addEdge(g,1,4);
        g.addEdge(g,2,3);
        g.addEdge(g,3,4);

        g.printGraph(g);
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: what's the current output ?

Comment: I was not getting any output in terminal. But in eclipse, it raised the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yes, it is expected! I have posted the fix in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't initialized elements with in `array` before you make a call to `this.array[i].head`. Hence you would be getting `NullPointerExcpetion`. Following fix should work

```
public graph(int V){
    this.V = V;
    this.array = new AdjList[V];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<V;++i){
        this.array[i] = new AdjList();
    }
}
```

Note:

1. You may follow Oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) on arrays to understand in detail about how arrays work in Java
2. I din't refactor other parts of your code